# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) - php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am getting this error:

> Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

The code passes the mysqli_connect but fails on mysql_select_db($db);
below is my code:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,'segokaku_user','SegokakuDB',$db); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
} 
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($db); 
if (!$db_selected) { 
    echo 'Can\'t use database : ' . mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: You are using the outdated mysql_ as well as the mysqli_ interfaces in the same script.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
mysqli_select_db($conn, $db)
```

instead

```
mysql_select_db($db)
```

I think it should solve your problem